# Open Google Maps Streetview in new tab shows wrong place

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-street-view

I have a feature in my web app where it opens a new tab and will show a google streetview on the coordinates that I provided.

These are the coordinates { latitude: -37.8136,  longitude: 144.9631 }. It should be somewhere in Melbourne(I searched it in google maps and I can verify that it is really in Melbourne) but if I open it in streetview it shows a place somewhere in Saudi Arabia. Whats weird is the mini map in lower left shows that Im still in Melbourne.

By the way this is the exact URL that I call when Im opening a new tab.
https://www.google.com/maps/@?api=1&map_action=pano&viewpoint=-37.8136,144.9631

[image: w]

Comment: Looks like a Google glitch to me. Changing the lat/long ever so slightly, it starts to look definitively Melbourne-y again - like https://www.google.com/maps/@?api=1&map_action=pano&viewpoint=-37.8137,144.9631 or https://www.google.com/maps/@?api=1&map_action=pano&viewpoint=-37.8136,144.9633 Guess this should be reported as a bug somewhere.

Comment: Thanks for this. But "glitch" still not 100% clear for me, I dont really understand what it means. So it might be someone accidentally put a wrong 360photo of Saudi Arabia into that exact coordinates? Well I already reported that photo to google as "Not appropriate photo of the place"

Comment: That appears to be Street View, those are the images taken by Google themselves, with their funny little cars driving around, and not user-created content. By “glitch”, as in “technical f*ck-up”, I meant that they probably associated some of that image material with the wrong coordinates.

Comment: The coordinates you provided seem to point to a location on the waters just east of Japan, and link you provided shows an indoor view of the Melbourne Airport. Are you still running into this problem?

Comment: Yes I still have the problem. As of now it is showing the indoors of Melbourne airport because I reported the "Saudi Arabia" photo last week as "Not appropriate photo of the place". After that, maybe 3 days, it shows the indoors of Melbourne airport which is a USER uploaded 360photo.

Comment: @MervinSamy No, not at all. Coordinates are in Melbourne, AU, and absolutely not *on the waters just east of Japan*